# When will this algorithm repeat itself?

Tags: algorithms

I was messing around with different ways of manipulating strings in Java when I came across the following algorithm.

Given a string, rearrange it as follows: first character, last character, second character, second to last character, etc etc. So for example, the string "test" would yield "ttes", which would yield "tste", which would yield "test" again.

I started trying out longer strings, assuming that the number of iterations that it would take for each string to "cycle around" would be equal to its length, as was the case with the "test" string. However, this is not the case. Each string of even length that was tested took a seemingly random number of iterations before cycling back around. Here's a graph of the first 1000 values of the number of iterations for a given string length:

[image: Graph]

As you can see just from the graph, there's really no easily findable pattern which can predict the number of iterations it will take for the random string to cycle around. The value seems to kind of just jump all over the place. So my question is, can anyone explain why the number of iterations behaves like it does? Is there any way to predict what the number of iterations needed for a string of a given length will be?

Here's a short program in Java that can calculate the number of iterations needed for a specific length. Replace the 1000 with whatever you want the max length of the string to be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int len = 1; len <= 1000; len++) {
        int count = 0;
        short[] value = build(len);
        do 
        {
            value = apply(value);
            count++;
        } 
        while (! done(value));
        System.out.printf("%d\t%d%n", len, count);
    }
}

private static short[] build(int len) 
{
    short[] value = new short[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        value[i] = (short)i;
    return value;
}

private static boolean done(short[] value) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
        if (value[i] != i)
            return false;
    return true;
}

private static short[] apply(short[] input) 
{
    short[] output = new short[input.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        output[i] = input[(i & 1) == 0 ? i / 2 : input.length - i / 2 - 1];
    return output;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by iterations? This can be done in $O(n)$ time for any length string. Use the same algorithm you would use to determine if a string is a palindrome but print the characters instead of checking them for equality.

Comment: By iteration I mean applying the rearranging rule. So, for example, for the string "test", an iteration would mean transforming "test" to "ttes". Another iteration would yield "tste", and another one would bring it back around to "test". My question is, is there any way to determine how many iterations are needed to "cycle around" a string back to its original state?

Comment: So what you want to find is the _order_ of the permutation $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2& 3 & 4 & \cdots & 2n-1 & 2n \\ 1 & 2n & 2 & 2n-1 & \cdots & n & n+1 \end{pmatrix}$$ (for even lengths) or (for odd lengths) $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2& 3 & 4 & \cdots & 2n-1 & 2n & 2n+1  \\ 1 & 2n+1 & 2 & 2n & \cdots & n & n+2 & n+2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: For odd length words, would the middle character go to the end because it is processed last?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, exactly

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes, because it is reached last by the algorithm